# How can i get Jquery UI datepicker to show up in asp.net gridview edit field

Tags: jquery, gridview, datepicker

I have a gridview inside an update panel, that is doing inline editing.  When edit is clicked, I need on of the textboxes to be a Jquery UI datepicker;

I've tried class and id selectors, tried child selector but Jquery can't set the thing as a datepicker because the element isn't really on the page yet.  So I tried adding a function to OnClientClick of the edit command and set the datepicker there but also doesn't seem to find the textbox.  It always stays a regular textbox.

Any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the textbox is added in UpdatePanel, then you need to hook up to the [end request](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383810.aspx).

```
// If my memory is good there was this pageLoad function that is 
// automatically called by the MS AJAX Framework when the DOM has finished loading
function pageLoad(sender, args) { 
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(
        function(sender, args) {
            $('your_textbox_selector').datepicker();
    }); 
}
```

If you have multiple update panels on your page you might need to tweak a little bit the end_request callback by checking the `sender` and `args` parameters, so that it attaches the datapicker only if the UpdatePanel that holds your GridView is triggered.

Comment: That's awesome!  Your 17.8k rep is well deserved.

Comment: That is probably why there is now 65.4k rep ;)